# referencing the source control in the CustomValidator control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, customvalidator

Is it possible to get a reference to the textbox that the customvalidator is 'attached' to in javascript?

I want to place a red border around the texbox if it fails validation.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to add tags. Can OP or someone add the ASP.Net tag to this post? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript validation function will have access to "sender" and "args" parameters. The control that is being validated may be accessed from the "sender" as follows.

```
function doValidation(sender, args)
{
    alert(sender.attributes["controltovalidate"].value);
}
```

Comment: No problem. It took me a while to figure out that one when I needed it myself.

Comment: Marked down because it doesn't work cross-browser, see my answer, below, for a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code provided by chrissr doesn't work in Firefox, but this works cross-browser (tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE7):

```
function doValidation(sender, args)
{
    alert(sender.controltovalidate);
}
```